# Trying to run Glassfish server on OpenShift in a DIY cartridge

Tags: java, ruby, glassfish, openshift

I'm trying to run Glassfish on OpenShift in a DIY cartridge  and I have a problem because I'm receiving an error saying that I can't bind the port 8080.

I have been talking with Openshift support and they have told me that I must remove a ruby file that is binding the 8080 port.

Error:

```
[#|2015-04-21T17:58:27.887-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : Permission denied: 8080=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@15ac5d5|#]
```

I think that I have done this, because I have removed a .rb file in the git directory but the problem persists.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your glassfish server is binding to port 8080 on your gear's ip address, which is your OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP environment variable.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial:
https://blog.openshift.com/running-java-apps-in-the-cloud-with-glassfish-and-a-paas/

Comment: Yesterday I reviewed the port of my server doing "env | grep OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT" and the result is 8080. Thus, I understand that this is the port that I should use but I think that other application is in this port and thus I'm receiving the previous error.

How can I know what application is binding this port and how can I remove it?